# PHP function return or echo with variable

Tags: php, progress-bar, twitter-bootstrap-3, user-defined-functions

So I am using a function which is used in two different places in a HTML, shown below.

```
function remaining($expDate,$output){
 $dStart = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
    $dEnd  = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d ',strtotime($expDate)));

    $dDiff = $dStart->diff($dEnd);
     $dDiff->format('%R'); 

  if($output = "return"){
        return $dDiff->days;
    }else{
        echo $dDiff->days;}
}
<div 
  class="progress-bar <?php if(remaining($expDate,"return")==90){echo"progress-bar-success";}else{echo "progress-bar-danger";}?> 
  role="progressbar" 
  aria-valuenow="40" 
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" 
  style="width: <?php remaining($expDate,"echo") ?>%">
```

When I return the value `style` part does not work, when I echo then in the `if()` statement I get the value :( So I tried to add a second argument and give a relative output.
I am obviously missing something here but could not figure it out :( Would you give me a hint on variable output on a function? Or may be a better way to achieve this:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the if statement

```
This is an attribution not a comparison
if( $output = "return" ){ ...
```

Should be something like:

```
function remaining($expDate,$output){
    $dStart = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
    $dEnd  = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d ',strtotime($expDate)));
    $dDiff = $dStart->diff($dEnd);
    return $dDiff->days;
}
```

AH!! By the way the code above works, you are not managing in getting it to work because you
forgot to do this: `<?php echo remaining()... ?>` you forgot the echo!

Regards.

Comment: Well just correcting the if statement made the trick. How I missed it :( Thank you very much @Joao

Comment: @cevizmx it's a common mistake ;)

Comment: @cevizmx check my update, that "output" thing you are doing is nasty :D!

Comment: @cevizmx by the way just an advise, next time try to be more careful with formatting or the guys here at SO could vote u down.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($output = "return")
```

Will always be true, correct it to

```
if($output == "return")
```

so the program compares and return either TRUE or FALSE

Answer (score 0):

```
if($output = "return"){
```

needs to be

```
if($output == "return"){
```

if you put

```
if($output = "return"){
```

then you effectively set $output to equal return (which will always return true!)

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement seems bad. You are using '=' which does not sound like the 'equals' operator  in PHP. So just replace '=' in your condition with '=='.

You may also prefer to pass a simple boolean here (true / false) instead of a string, but that is up to you.